# Cannot access Jenkins from browser ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, installation

I installed jenkins on my Ubuntu server. It says its running but I can't connect with the browser from my local computer and I don't have access to the server's desktop to check if I can connect from localhost.

**Additional information:**

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins.service
```

Returns:

● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-09-13 14:46:08 -03; 1h 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 29259 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 29308 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 jenkins[29308]: Correct java version found
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 jenkins[29308]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 su[29341]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 su[29341]: + ??? root:jenkins
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 su[29341]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Sep 13 14:46:08 vp-smg2-lnx0010 jenkins[29308]:    ...done.
Sep 13 14:46:08 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.

```
netstat -ntulp | grep 8090
```

Returns:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

`tail /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`

Returns (last lines):

Sep 13, 2018 2:46:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@5220af81: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Sep 13 14:46:24 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 13, 2018 2:46:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@5220af81]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1dccc1f3
Sep 13, 2018 2:46:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1dccc1f3: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 13, 2018 2:46:24 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Sep 13, 2018 2:46:24 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running

```
journalctl -xe
```

Returns:

### ` -- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[29342]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[29342]: Startup finished in 38ms.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is

### -- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.

### -- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.

### -- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.

-- Userspace start-up required 38392 microseconds.
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 116.
-- Subject: Unit user@116.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit user@116.service has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 14:46:07 vp-smg2-lnx0010 su[29341]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
Sep 13 14:46:08 vp-smg2-lnx0010 jenkins[29308]:    ...done.
Sep 13 14:46:08 vp-smg2-lnx0010 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit jenkins.service has finished starting up.

-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 14:46:08 vp-smg2-lnx0010 sudo[29305]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 13 14:46:12 vp-smg2-lnx0010 sudo[29373]: administrador : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log/jenkins ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status jenkins.service `

I'm setting jenkins to run on port 8090, and my ufw status is:

`To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8081                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8090                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8081 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8090 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`

```
curl -i localhost:8090
```

Returns:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: 
JSESSIONID.a54dcd68=node018je3pqsr2xyroubaw1ypmg4e2.node0;Path=/;HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
X-Hudson: 1.395
X-Jenkins: 2.138.1
X-Jenkins-Session: 79f324ac
X-You-Are-Authenticated-As: anonymous
X-You-Are-In-Group-Disabled: JENKINS-39402: use - 
Dhudson.security.AccessDeniedException2.REPORT_GROUP_HEADERS=true or use 
/whoAmI 
to diagnose
X-Required-Permission: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
Content-Length: 677
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)

<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/> 
<script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body 
style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

I have other browser applications on the same server running on port 80 and 8080 and I can access them normally. I've tried to access it from ip-address:8090 and ip-address:8090/jenkins and both failed with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT time out error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. It turned out that I didn't have port 8080 open on that server, so I asked the company to open it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

it will be because of Security inbound Rules.

Go to Security Groups->inbound rules-> allow 8080 port->Protocol(TCP) and source (0.0.0.0/0)

That may work!

Answer (score 0):

I change the network (Wi-Fi) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

‘Err Connection Timed Out’ is one of the most common internet errors.

FIX: Edit the Windows Host file
Sometimes we use the windows host file to block access to some websites, 
Just check the host file and see if there is any URL or IP address.
The host file is located at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Right click on Notepad > Run as Administrator.
After launching Notepad, click on File, and then browse to **c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc** location.

Click on all files. You will see a list of files. Click on "hosts" and select open.

Scroll down the file and check for URLs or IPs after the last # symbol.

In my case, I had assigned a **DNS** for my **jenkins local host**. The IP had changed,hence this error occured.